# Converting string to int and then back to string

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to convert my string variable to an integer to add a value (+1) to it but the result I get is:

```
1111
```

Infact I should be getting a total of 4 when I reconvert it to string.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public string str_Val = "1";

void Update () {
if (str_Val  != "5") {
      str_Val  = int.Parse (str_Val + 1).ToString ();
   }
}
```

Comment: `(int.Parse (str_Val) + 1).ToString()`?

Comment: @Charlieface Ah outside the bracket. Thanks!

Comment: You are adding +1 to the string BEFORE you convert it to an INT.  You need to convert to INT, then add 1, then convert back to string

Comment: You are parsing the result of `"1" + 1` not adding to the result of a parsed "1".

Comment: Thanks alot guys. :)

Comment: If you need to increment it, why is your var a `string` then? Make it an `int`. Do `ToString()` where necessary.

Comment: Is the value to increment always bigger than 0 and lower than 5?

Comment: @Steve Yes always bigger than 0.

Comment: You definitely rather want to go with what @Fildor said .. there is absolutely no good reason why you should store that as a `string` in the first place ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's all about the priority of the actions:

```
int.Parse (str_Val + 1)
```

In the row above first the addition happens `str_Val + 1` outputing `11`,`111`,`111` etc.

Then the parsing occurs changing `"11"` to `11`

Then to string occurs changing `11` to `"11"`

So change your code to

```
str_Val  = (int.Parse(str_Val)+1).ToString();
```

This will first convert the string to int, then add two integers and finally convert the integer to string again.

Comment: "_then add two integers_" it is adding only 1

Answer (score 1):

you are concatenating 1 to the string before parsing, that is the reason of the behavior on your code...

so you are doing:

> "1" + 1
>
> "11"
>
> Parse  to int ("11")
>
> convert to string(11)

do instead:

```
if (str_Val  != "5")
{
      str_Val  = (int.Parse(str_Val) + 1).ToString ();
   }
}
```