# Converting a range of strings to int for addition

Tags: c#

This is an extension of the question asked here:
[Converting string to int and then back to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66226169/converting-string-to-int-and-then-back-to-string)

I am now converting a range of string values to add all of them together. I obviously cannot do something like:

```
int Total;
string str1 = "1";
string str2 = "1";
string str3 = "1";
string str4 = "1";
string str5 = "1";
string str6 = "1";
...
...

void Start()
{
  Total = int.Parse(str1) + int.Parse(str2) + .....
}
```

I am looking for a way to parse all the strings into int such that:

```
Total = int.Parse(str1 + str2 + str3 + ...)
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I don't know what background you have, perhaps PHP, but stop applying that background to C#. You should not need to parse strings to integers that often. You definitely should not have numbered variables, you need an array instead. Then you can iterate over that array and do the parsing and addition. Just as with your previous question, you now will parse "111111", which is not what you want. _Why_ do you want to do this?

Comment: Thing is I am extending a code of someone who imports the values from the server as a string.

Comment: It's no shame to rewrite broken code into something that does work. Your question is also unclear. Why can you obviously not do something like the code you've shown? It does work, if you ignore the unnecessary string to int part. Or do you mean that you don't know how many `strN` variables you'll have? Even more reason to use an array or list instead of numbered variables.

Comment: So you are extending some code you know is poorly written, that is a ticking bomb waiting to happen

Comment: Yes I am not sure how many string variables I will have. Yes I thought of array/list to use but I was hoping that is there a way to add all the strings to int.Parse() instead of adding int.Parse() to each of the string

Comment: _"I am not sure how many string variables I will have"_ - then how should the compiler know? Again, rethink your approach. This approach is not going to work and/or not going to be maintainable.

Comment: This is an [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You are asking about a problem caused because of a wrong/poor analysis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you do not know how many values you will have, you cannot hardcode all the single values into independent variables.

**Advice**: You should really consider storing the data in the correct format, You approach should be working with integers instead of strings (using a `List<int>`). The code would be more bug resistant and more simple.

```cs
int Total = 0;
List<string> valuesToAdd = new List<string>(){
    "1",
    "4",
    "1",
    "99"
};

void Start()
{
    Total = 0;
    foreach(string stringValue in valuesToAdd)
    {
        Total += int.Parse(stringValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as an alternative, LINQ could be used to write this in a single line (if preferable): `Total = new[] { "1", "4", "1", "99" }.Sum(s => int.Parse(s));`

Comment: @ThomasArdal Before answering the question I checked the related question OP put in their question and decided to not suggest LINQ, but to present him an easier to understand approach

Comment: Probably a good idea  Was thinking more for future visitors.